# Get Product price by customer Group magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, customer, price, customer-group

I am trying to get Product price by customer group. Used below code.

```
$sku = 123;
$customerGroup = $this->getCustomerGroupId();
$currentProduct = $this->loadProduct($sku);
$productPrice = $currentProduct->getPrice();

 public function loadProduct($sku)
 {
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
 }

public function getCustomerGroupId(){
    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerGroup = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        return $customerGroup;
    }
    return;
}
```

Above code returning the product final price.

Can we get product price by customer Group code?

```
 $customerGroup
```

is returing the current customer group that is id = 5 in my case. How to get the product price from customer group?

Can anyone look into this and update me your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one but don't use ObjectManager, you can inject Magento\Catalog\Model\Product &  \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface class in constructor:

```
$productId = 9;//your product id here

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$productAllTierPrices = $_product->getData('tier_price');

$allTierPrices = array();
foreach($productAllTierPrices as $tierPrices){
    $groupname = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface')-> getById($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
    $allTierPrices[$groupname] = $tierPrices['price'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($allTierPrices);
```

Comment: Please provide solution as per class constructor

Comment: @groy, I have already customer group id, from that how can i get the product price,?

Comment: @jafarpinjar: Code updated with respect to customerGroupId.

Comment: @groy, tried your answer, page not working error i am getting !!

Comment: @groy, I think ->getById($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode(); may be the error

Comment: @jafarpinjar: Did you notice the class name? I have changed the class name also but try once. It should work.

Comment: this does not work for bundle product and grouped products